# Is it Possible to Add Email Addresses to the Notification Settings of an Automation via the API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, automationstudio, notification, marketingcloudapi

I am creating automations through the API and would like to add email addresses to the "Notification Settings" fields in the "Activity" tab. Is this possible to do through either SOAP or REST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. There is no way to add an email to the notification settings of an automation.

Actually, there is an option in the Soap request on the help page that "normally" adds this parameter, but under a comment that clearly stats that it **does not work**: Check out the comment on the `Notifications` tag

```
<!--<Notifications> DOES NOT WORK
      <Notification>
        <Address>swhitmore@salesforce.com</Address>
        <NotificationType>-1</NotificationType>
      </Notification>
     </Notifications>-->
```

========== ============= =====

**Update:**

Actually, the answer is ***YES***. I have conducted multiple tests today and found out that there is a problem on the [documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm).

They are not using the correct values for the parameters on their SOAP request.

So, to sum things up, make a POST SOAP api call using something like below.

`NotificationType` value should be one of these two:

- Error
- Complete

Leave the `channeltype` as it is.

```
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
            <Client>
               <ID>50000xxxx</ID>
            </Client>
            <Name>AUT_ONEOFF4</Name>
            <CustomerKey>AUT_ONEOFF4</CustomerKey>
            <Description>AUT_ONEOFF4</Description>
               <Notifications>
                <Notification>
                 <ChannelType>1</ChannelType>
                 <NotificationType>Complete</NotificationType>
                 <Address>youremail_address@gmail.com</Address>
                </Notification>
               </Notifications>
            <AutomationType>scheduled</AutomationType>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
```

Don't forget to change the clientID.

Comment: I cannot believe you figured this out, thank you so much!! This worked perfectly for me. I wish this could get added to the official documentation so that others could find it as well.

Comment: Glad I can help.. I'll get in touch as soon as possible with Salesforce regarding this ..

Comment: i cant seem to be able to RETRIEVE it that info though. any hints?